# Can I add javascript popup boxes in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just want a simple Ok, cancel javascript popup. When I click an image i want it to open a popup and as if you want to continue or cancel.

```
{
  "name": "SafeTick",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Browse safely",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "SafeTick",
    "default_popup": "extention.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

I don't know if I need the

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
```

and add the popup in the background script.

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Comment: By javascript popup you mean the `confirm` function, or a JS modal on the page?

Comment: @RayWu a confirm function

Comment: Well, then use the [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) function? You need a content script for that, not a background script. See the documentation.